# using multiple conditions to list HITs using aws mturk cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, mechanicalturk

I have 2 queries to obtain hits:

1) `` aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[?HITStatus==`Assignable`].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus, "4. HITTypeID": HITTypeId}'  --max-results 100 ``

2) `` aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[?HITTypeId==`ABCD1234`].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus, "4. HITTypeID": HITTypeId}'  --max-results 100 ``

Now I want to obtain a hit that satisfies both the conditions. AWS Mturk CLI uses JMESPath Specification. Not much aware of it and couldn't grasp it's docs on the first go.

I tried the following to combine both the conditions:

```
aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[?HITTypeId==`ABCD1234` && ?HITStatus==`Assignable`].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus, "4. HITTypeID": HITTypeId}'  --max-results 100
```

```
aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[?HITTypeId==`ABCD1234`, ?HITStatus==`Assignable`].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus, "4. HITTypeID": HITTypeId}'  --max-results 100
```

Both of them don't seem to work.

Please help in rectifying the syntax to list HITs using multiple conditions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by BruteForce :p

Here's something that worked.

```
aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[?HITTypeId==`ABCD` && HITStatus==`Unassignable`].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus, "4. HITTypeID": HITTypeId}' --max-results 100
```

Question mark needs to be put only once.